# Short science-fiction story about a guy stationed on a stranded planet and a Martian woman who accompanied him

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Before going there he buys a Martian woman to be his sex slave. During the story he treats her badly and thinks of her as a lesser being who is too dumb to act in her defense. In the end the slave locks him out of the station, and when he tries to drill his way back in the Martian slave builds a bomb that would explode in case of depressurization and shows it to him to stop him from trying that. Finally the man dies while the Martian woman sits calmly in the station and reads something.

Comment: Can you recall when you read this, or any other details about it?

Comment: it was around 15 years ago. I read it in a science magazine but it was translated to my language (not English). the name of the story was something like "Stupid Martian" or something like that but I can't be sure about the original name of the story.

Comment: You don’t happen to recall which magazine it was published in, do you? Some of our users may have (limited or native) proficiency in various languages, so knowing that could still help.

Comment: I'm from Iran, the magazine was called "Etela'ate elmi" which in persian means "scientific information"

Comment: Yes. My bad.But as you can see the answer has already been posted. Turns out it wasn't even a planet. It was Jupiter IV/II, a sub-moon of Callisto (itself a moon of Jupiter).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

***Dumb Martian***, by John Wyndham.

You can read it in archive.org: https://archive.org/details/DumbMartian or, in [a better OCRed pdf, here](https://ia800803.us.archive.org/1/items/DumbMartian/DumbMartianByJohnWyndham1952.pdf).

A small description [from studymode.com](http://www.studymode.com/essays/Examine-How-John-Wyndham-In-%E2%80%98Dumb-160526.html):

> In the short story ‘Dumb Martian’ written by John Wyndham, the main character, Lellie’s life changes dramatically when she lock Duncan out of the dome and starts to challenge Duncan.

Comment: You might want to link to [the pdf](https://ia800803.us.archive.org/1/items/DumbMartian/DumbMartianByJohnWyndham1952.pdf) or just https://archive.org/details/DumbMartian . The txt is OCRed very badly.

Comment: @CodesinChaos You are right. Thanks for the info.

Comment: what an interesting story. John Wyndham mocks racism, sexism, classism, "know-nothing-ism", and space utopianism. In 1952.

Comment: @Spike0xff You should read _The Day Of the Triffids_ sometime and see how he feltabout post-apocalyptic "survivalists" building their would-be fashy empires on the ashes. He was a wise man.